# PowerShell Disable Bluetooth on Windows 7

Tags: powershell, bluetooth

I am creating a Windows 7 image via SCCM and would like to disable Bluetooth via a Task Sequence, so far I have the following below.
I am getting a error regarding the path as it has spaces in it, I think it is due to the $ScriptPath. Could I get some help on this, cheers all.

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$BTDisabled = $False

$id = Get-CimInstance Win32_PnPEntity | where caption -like 'Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)'
$id = $id.DeviceID
$ppid = "{0}{1}" -f '@',$id 
Write-host "This is the PPID...  "
Write-Host $PPID
$devcon = $ScriptPath + "\devcon64.exe"
Write-Host "Going to invoke expression..."

$PIDStatus = Invoke-Expression "$devcon status ""$ppid"""

Write-Host "Invoked Expression completed..."
Write-Host $PIDStatus

if ($PIDStatus -like '*disabled*') {$BTDisabled = $True}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Bluetooth is disabled : " $BTDisabled
```

Comment: Do you have the `devcon64.exe` file available at the same location where your script is located?

Comment: yes i do, how do I get it work when the path has spaces in it?

Comment: $devcon = """$ScriptPath\devcon64.exe"""

Comment: I've got the whole path now thank you, but it is saying "is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet, function...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code where I updated line number 12 to deal with quotes:

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$BTDisabled = $False

$id = Get-CimInstance Win32_PnPEntity | where caption -like 'Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)'
$id = $id.DeviceID
$ppid = "{0}{1}" -f '@',$id 
Write-host "This is the PPID...  "
Write-Host $PPID
$devcon = $ScriptPath + "\devcon64.exe"
Write-Host "Going to invoke expression..."

$PIDStatus = Invoke-Expression "& '$devcon' status `"$ppid`""

Write-Host "Invoked Expression completed..."
Write-Host $PIDStatus

if ($PIDStatus -like '*disabled*') {$BTDisabled = $True}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Bluetooth is disabled : " $BTDisabled
```

Comment: If i use the Invoke-expression part I get "& : The term 'C:\PATH\Path 2\Scripts\devcon64.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" if I take Invoke-Expression out it runs but doesnt do anything, if I change 'Status' to 'Disable' it doesnt disable the bluetooth adapter

Comment: That was the reason I asked earlier if you can find `devcon64.exe` at this path: `C:\PATH\Path 2\Scripts\devcon64.exe`

Comment: My bad, your updated script worked. I have the wrong exe name, the quotes you put it helped heaps cheers.

Comment: Please accept the solution that worked for you, in order to close the question. Thanks.